# about qt6 qtquick QML in macos.move rectangle but leave transparent shadow box，otherwise the interface background is completely transparent

Tags: qtquick2, qt6

First,this picture is my creat UI, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRSZj.png)
the next pic is the UI after move rectangle[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPg6E.png)
obversly，rectangle move but leave a shadow with a frame。
after my test,this phenomenon will occur as long as a rectangle is moved using animation，on a transparent background.
this effect is not what i expected。
otherwise,windows have not this phenomenon ,only macos have this phenomenon.

the key code will be presented below.

```
c++
QGuiApplication app(argc,argv);
QQuickViewer viewer;
viewer.setColor(Qcolor(Qt::transparennt));
viewer.setFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
viewer.setFlag(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/QTQA-Creator/Main.qml"));
viewer.show();
```

```
qml

Rectangle {
    id: mainRectangle  
    objectName: "mainRectangle"
    width: 850
    height: 600
    color:Qt.rgba(0,0,0,0)

    Rectangle{
        id: mainPageRectangle   
        objectName: "mainPageRectangle"
        width: 770
        height: 600
        radius: 10
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: Qt.rgba(220/255,42/255,214/255,0.6) }
            //GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "green" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: Qt.rgba(80/255,30/255,247/255,0.6) }
        }
        Rectangle{
            id:ttes
            width: 50
            height: 50
            color: "yellow"
        }
    }
    PathAnimation {
        id: parabolaAnimation
        target: mainPageRectangle
        duration: 1000 
        path: Path {
            startX: 0; startY: 0 
            PathQuad {
                x: 20; y: 0 
                controlX: 100; controlY: 300
            }
            PathQuad {
                x: 50; y: 0 
                controlX: 300; controlY: 100
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted:{
        parabolaAnimation.start();
    

    }
}
```

this code run in windows without this problem ,the macos have this problem .

if cancel `viewer.setColor(Qcolor(Qt::transparennt));` this problem also display.

I make some new attempt。
Place mouse on the soft frame,[as the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8BpH.jpg)
hold and move，[result pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQll2.jpg)
the soft frame exist，but the shadow and black frame don't exist.